A graph with stacked column (3 data) with scatter points
example of a graph that contains stacked column with scatter points
How do I create a graph that contain a stacked column (3 data range) and a scatter points data as per image attached

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Can you share us with a simple sample?

This article might be useful to you for the dot plot part of this: https://peltiertech.com/make-technical-dot-plots-in-excel/
Other articles by Jon Peltier should cover the box plot part of this, and if you scroll to the comments he shows an example of combining them just like your link.
